# Android studio EditText input color difficult to see on Dark Mode

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-edittext, darkmode

I am developing a mobile app and there is a default day and night theme. The day theme is working perfectly fine, however on the night/dark theme, the edit text input color is difficult to see. The color of the text changes between day and night themes, but the dark theme seems off, I've tried changing it in the values/themes.xml file but it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

These are the comparison between day/light and night/dark mode.
day/light mode:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/usaqH.png

night/dark mode:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkGLh.png